# armor payments API - rails integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment

I'm having a hard time integrating the Armor Payments API into my rails app. There is sample code in the integration guide, but no clear instructions on what goes where. I've been working with rails the past 2 months and just need some guidance on using API's. This is the guide http://www.armorpayments.com/api/pages/integrationGuide/goods.html can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can access Armor Payments Ruby Client library @ https://github.com/Armor-Payments/armor_payments_ruby which can help you in the API integration.

Let me know if you need any help in using the client library...